# Empty result when i implement the use of functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

So i have solved my last problem (with your help) but I wanted to make my program run a lot smoother by the use of functions. Now I have declared and written everything right ( I think) but when I execute my code it doesn't do anything. Any help?

It is supposed to show a hourglass matching the amount of time that has passed, with a max time of 480 seconds.

All of the 'if's ' are properly indented in my code so that's not the problem. I just forgot to that here.

```
from graphics import GraphicsWindow

def main():
    win = GraphicsWindow(400, 400)
    canvas = win.canvas()
    canvas.setBackground("white")
    mc=makechoice()
    while mc==yes or mc==Yes:
        canvas.clear()
        hourglass()
    print(' End of session. ')

def makechoice():
    mc = input(' Do you want to make use of the hourglass app?. ')
    return mc


def hourglass():
    dt = int(input('How much time has passed? (In seconds). '))
if dt==0:
    canvas.setOutline("blue")
    canvas.setFill("blue")
    canvas.drawPolygon(150, 50, 250, 50, 200, 130)
    canvas.setFill("white")
    canvas.drawPolygon(200, 130, 150, 210, 250, 210)
    win.wait()
elif dt==480:
    canvas.setOutline("blue")
    canvas.setFill("white")
    canvas.drawPolygon(150, 50, 250, 50, 200, 130)
    canvas.setFill("blue")
    canvas.drawPolygon(200, 130, 150, 210, 250, 210)
    win.wait()
elif dt>0 and dt<480:
    x1 = 150 + ((((250 / 480) * dt) - ((150 / 480) * dt)) / 3.1)
    x2 = 250 - ((((250 / 480) * dt) - ((150 / 480) * dt)) / 3.1)
    x3=200-(((250/480*dt)-(150/480*dt))/2)
    x4=200+(((250/480*dt)-(150/480*dt))/2)
    y1=50+(50/480)*dt
    y2=210-(80/480*dt)
    y3=210
    canvas.setOutline("blue")
    canvas.setFill("white")
    canvas.drawPolygon(150, 50, 250, 50, 200, 130)
    canvas.setFill("white")
    canvas.drawPolygon(200, 130, 150, 210, 250, 210)
    canvas.setFill("blue")
    canvas.drawPolygon(x1, y1, x2, y1, 200, 130)
    canvas.setFill("blue")
    canvas.drawPolygon(200,y2,x3,y3,x4,y3)
    win.wait()
elif dt<0 or dt>480:
    print(' This choice is invalid. ')
```

Comment: Do you ever call `main()` ? (I'm guessing not because you'll then get `NameError`s which you'll need to fix by using string literals)

Comment: You need to show where you're calling it then or else we're missing relevant code... Also - you can't be calling it as like I said you'd hit other errors when you did...

Comment: you mean like this?:

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        def main():

with the main() indented?

Comment: You don't need to define main - you've done that... to start with - just put `main()` at the bottom of the code you've posted...